# Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When I try upload my app to app store I get the following error: "Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error". Have anyone ever get this message? Is it due to an Apple developer portal problem?

[image]

IDEDistribution.critical.log:

```
2017-01-06 15:32:14 +0000  The store submission configuration response failed with errors: (
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1614 \"Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}"
), warnings: (
), info messages: (
).
2017-01-06 15:32:16 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=1614 "Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup the settings for submission for the application at this time due to a general error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=iTunes Store operation failed.}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same. Tried uploading a new app last night. Same issue persists. This is only my second app store app, so I'm sure something else is wrong, but since its a "general" error, and you're seeing it, its also possible that their service is having issues.

Comment: This is the only thing I've seen so far mentioning this, so I'll lurk here and hope somebody has more info. My deploy isn't really time sensitive. I'm sure others aren't in the same situation.

Comment: If you're a new apple developer you'll need to get used to this sort of nonsense. Don't expect any help from apple, StackOverflow is the only place worth going to for anything useful. I used to find it easier to develop printer drivers in the eighties using a biro and a breakout box.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found the solution, before uploading the app by xcode, you should create the app at http://itunesconnect.apple.com/

[image]

Comment: That did it. Surprised the error message was so general.

Comment: Agh, that's the answer. Unbelievably useless error message, which is all too common across all of Apple's platform. Well found, Sir.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and after playing around I realized that when updating a new version of an app, the "Bundle ID" must match the original version "Bundle ID".

Matching the Bundle ID to my version 1.0 upload solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem, and I realized I made spelling mistake of bundle Id...

Comment: Can give more detail about the solution. This will help later for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same for the last couple of hours.
From the verbose.log:

> Bundle ID based store submission configuration response received = (null)

Looks like a problem at their end.

Comment: Then, what is the solution?

Comment: Actually for me I realised I was using the wrong Identifier (listed on the right of the archives list in Xcode under 'details'). If you have previously successfully uploaded an earlier version of your app then check the identifier - it should be the same as the value for 'Bundle ID' in iTunes Connect->App Information->General Information. This value is set as 'Product Bundle Identifier' in Build Settings->Packaging in your Xcode project file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I went to analyze my account on Itunes, I realized that I was as a Developer. To create apps and send versions to iTunes you must also have access to the Application Manager function

Answer (score 0):

In Itune connect，App info： group ID + suffix ID must be as same as your Bundle ID in Xcode Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had specified the wrong bundle ID in my app settings in xCode. It didn't match the bundle ID I had specified in iTunes connect.

Basically this setting in xCode:

[image]

Needs to match this setting in iTunes Connect:

[image]